# DateTime.TryParseExact() is returning false

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I have the following code

```
public static void Main()
{
    DateTime D = new DateTime();
    D = DateTime.Now;

    string s1 = D.ToString("ddMMMMyyyy");
    Console.WriteLine(s1);

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact(s1, "ddMMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out D));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Could someone please help me realise the obvious mistake I am making.

I converted `DateTime.Now` into a string in a custom format and tried to convert it back, but `TryParseExact` is returning false.

Comment: Use a `string` variable (probably a `const`) to represent the format. This way you'll avoid magic strings and repetition, and such problems won't occur in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: `MMMM` does not equal `MMM`.

A Sidenote: parsing such strings with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` will only recognize English names, it seems that it will fail on machines with other languages.

Comment: feel like kicking myself right now . hehe thanks a lot.

Comment: No i needed that format, wasnt an arbitrary one. Had to store the date as a table name in mysql

Comment: @Nahum Litvin: That was a pretty bold edit to someone else's answer. Sorry, I've rolled back the code you put it because it does not seem to compile right on my machine (your code returned 1.1.0001 as a date). Please consider posting a seperate answer with tested code.